# Hedging XVA sensitivities and funding risk

Tags: cva, fva, xva

FVA is a hot topic today and I've been thinking on how its managed inside a treasury department.

Although the pricing/calculation is well covered in academic material and there is some sort of consesud in the methodology (generate some funding profile and apply some funding spread), the management and hedging is not well understood.

For example, if we generate a an expected funding profile and hedge the funding risk with assets/libabilities, we are still open to the fluctuations in the profile, meaning that we would require extra/less funding that what we projected and dynamic hedging aren't feasible in liquidity markets.

How is this adjustment usually managed in banks? I'm clear that i might be charged to dealing desk, but after that, how liquidity is managed? What about the other xva components like KVA?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an explicit example of the sorts of positions you are discussing? Say, an unsecured fixed rate loan asset to a customer (i.e. an FRN with an uncollateralised IRS overlay) hedged by a collateralised, and cleared, interest rate swap (IRS)?

Comment: I'm thinking on a standard setup, for example, an uncolletarized swap with a client and hedged with CSA counterparty. In this case, FVA would arrise from the fact that we need to fund the collateral.